# how to compare words and find match words in R

Tags: r

I have data frame like this:

```
     var1                           var2                     result  
 c("apple", "www")            c("apple", "zzz")           "apple" 
 c("dog", "cat", "kkk")       c("cat", "kkk")             "cat", "kkk"
```

I want to find words that overlap in these two variables(var1 and var2) in dataframe in R.

Comment: Question in unclear, please read and edit your question according to: [How to make a great R reproducible example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: var1[var1 %in% var2]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think data.frame() can handle vectors as individual elements, so I used `data_frame()` from the `tibble` package:

```
df <- tibble::data_frame(var1 = list(c("apple", "www"), c("dog", "cat", "kkk")), var2 = list(c("apple", "zzz"), c("cat", "kkk")))
```

apply function by row, where the function takes the intersection of the first and second list elements:

```
apply(df, 1, function(x) intersect(x[[1]], x[[2]]))
[[1]]
[1] "apple"

[[2]]
[1] "cat" "kkk"
```